# Adjusting Row Height Dynamically in Excel Output: Additional Lines Added in Cell?

Tags: python, linux, pandas, xlsxwriter

I've rewritten this to simplify to the current problem:

I need to use pandas and xlsxwriter to dynamically enlarge row sizes in MS Windows Excel 2007+ based on the text length in a particular column in each row. I am working with a more experienced developer but we can't seem to make it happen without a stingy error coming about, there are certain, seemingly random, rows that have extra white space at the bottom:

I've included the formatting code and an image of the unsatisfactory output below:

```
#this is the formatting which is being applied on the column with the wrapped text:

description_format = workbook.add_format({'font_name': 'Arial', 'font_size': 9, 'bold': False, 'text_wrap': True, 'bottom': 1, 'top': 2, 'left': 0, 'right': 0})

#this is the formatting being applied to all cells:

format5 = workbook.add_format({'font_name': 'Arial', 'font_size': 9, 'bold': False, 'text_wrap': True, 'valign': 'top'})
```

[Here is the image of the output, with the extra white space at the bottom of the rows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOAyE.png)

Comment: Calculating the height accurately will be hard without access to the font and cell metrics that Excel uses. An alternative might be to set the [`text_wrap`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#format-set-text-wrap) property of the cell/column and allow Excel to automatically set the row height when the file loads. This would require not setting the row height or format.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm having the other developer take a look. I'll check back in on whether or not we could make it work.

Comment: So we were able to go back in and set the text_wrap and valign manually as you suggested by not setting the row height or format, unfortunately we still end up with, seemingly, random rows that have additional vertical space in them but now, as I guessed we might have a problem with if we were able to fix the valign issue in the OP, all of the additional white space is appearing at the bottom of the rows in question. Any idea what might be happening to cause this?

Comment: Just edited the original post to show updated formatting code.